# Typing node looks in /usr/sbin/node instead of /usr/bin/node

Tags: node.js, bash, unix

I installed `nodejs` and then `node` using `aptitude`. After that I purged `node` and created a link from `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `/usr/bin/node`. Now, when I typed `node`, for some unknown reason it keeps looking in `sbin` instead of `bin`. To check I purged `nodejs` too and typed both `node` and `nodejs` and following is the output.

```
(mvenv)username@mymachine:~$ node
-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory
(mvenv)username@mymachine:~$ nodejs
-bash: /usr/bin/nodejs: No such file or directory
```

Any explanation why typing `node` makes bash to look inside `sbin` instead of `bin` whereas for a similar command `nodejs` it looks in `bin`? And how can I possibly break this `sbin` link and restore to `bin`?

Comment: What is in the PATH environment variable? Do /usr/bin/nodejs and /usr/sbin/node exist? Particularly are they symlinks to non-existent files?

Comment: Your shell remembers where it found commands (to avoid needing to look them up each time). A new session should find the correct new locations. You can use `hash -r` to make the shell forget all saved locations or `hash -d node nodejs` to forget just those entries.

Comment: No. They don't exist. /user/sbin/node was never any symlink. I made a symlink to /usr/bin/node which didn't get called. Probably because my previous installation of node. And the system didn't rehash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All I needed to do was rehash. So, typing the following solved it.

```
$ hash -r
```

Thanks Etan Reisner for this too. It deletes missing links.

```
$ hash -d node nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks @Sidmeister this helped fix my node installation on Ubuntu (15) server!